# Find coordinates in canvas Gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I've made a graph using gnuplot and converted it to a png-file (Canvas). I want to know the exact coordinate for every point in the generated png-file but the problem is that the graph is in the middle of the canvas which gives me the wrong coordinates. Hope it wasn't too hard to follow.. Could upload a picture if it would make it easier to understand..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to get.  Do you want to be able to count pixels to find a coordinate?  Please do add a picture to your question if you think it will help.

Comment: better clarify what canvas means. wikipedia disambiguation page yields sevarl possabilites that might make sense here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Imagemagic](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) you can get a text file with coordinates and colors of every pixel

```
convert example.png example.txt
```

**example.txt:**

```
# ImageMagick pixel enumeration: 275,297,255,rgb
0,0: (159,159,159)  #9F9F9F  rgb(159,159,159)
1,0: (172,172,172)  #ACACAC  rgb(172,172,172)
2,0: (172,172,172)  #ACACAC  rgb(172,172,172)
3,0: (172,172,172)  #ACACAC  rgb(172,172,172)
4,0: (172,172,172)  #ACACAC  rgb(172,172,172)
5,0: (172,172,172)  #ACACAC  rgb(172,172,172)
6,0: (172,172,172)  #ACACAC  rgb(172,172,172)
7,0: (172,172,172)  #ACACAC  rgb(172,172,172)
8,0: (172,172,172)  #ACACAC  rgb(172,172,172)
```

Comment: I don't know if this is the answer, but dang ... This is cool.

Comment: Sorry for late answer, will try it out! Thanks! :)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Works as a charm!